# Long running Django process feasible?

Tags: django, performance, orm, redis, daemon

Is there a (recommended) way to run Django as a long running single process (that handles queued requests)?

I'm attempting to solve a performance problem where best projected performance tuning will still not be fast enough for production. Both tuned DB requests and caching end up taking up too much time in deserialization.

Furthermore the querysets are fairly static.

As such, it would seem one option for solving the performance issue would be to make calculations on existing executed/realized querysets from a long running process.

Anyone aware of a way to run django in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Because Django is in Python, you can quite easily run part on the application as a script, running on the server, either as a `cron` job or constantly running.

If the script is in the project directory, you need to start with these lines:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<module>.settings")
```

In which `<module>` is the directory containing the `settings.py` file.

You can then access the objects and function normally, for example:

```
from app.models import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyObj.objects.all()
```

Comment: The problem here is accepting requests. I still want to accept requests, but from within the same process so I can effectively share data in memory across requests.